# WordPress add to database from form

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add content from a form to a WordPress database using `$wpdb`

I have used `$wpdb` a few time but never to update and never in conjunction with input fields and I'm having a few issues with it.

bellow is the php and the form I have written up:

```
<form method="post">
  <input class="totaltrsut" type="text" value="" name="totaltrsut">
  <input class="totalreviews" type="number" value="" name="totalreviews">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $newToken; ?>">
  <input class="committodb" type="submit" value="Add Stats">
</form>
<?php
 global $wpdb;
 $successa=$wpdb::update( 'dc_additional', array( 'addi_value' => $_POST['totaltrsut'] ), array( 'addi_value' => 1 ), array( '%s', '%d' ), array( '%d' ) );
 $successb=$wpdb::update( 'dc_additional', array( 'addi_value' => $_POST['totalreviews'] ), array( 'addi_value' => 2 ), array( '%s', '%d' ), array( '%d' ) );
if($successa && $successb){echo 'data has been save';}
?>
```

What's supposed to happen is the form updates the additional table's `addi_value` column with the corresponding information based on the `add_id`.

Comment: $wpdb->update , this is right way, $wpdb::update is not right way, because $wpdb is not static class.

Comment: @TheFallen Sorry but this has nothing to do with posts and $wpdb is the function for updating specific data within a database using wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make one change in your code.

$wpdb is a global variable. it's not a static class.

[Wordpress $wpdb->update codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows).

** Updated Code:**

```
<form method="post">
  <input class="totaltrsut" type="text" value="" name="totaltrsut">
  <input class="totalreviews" type="number" value="" name="totalreviews">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $newToken; ?>">
  <input class="committodb" type="submit" value="Add Stats">
</form>
<?php
 global $wpdb;
 $successa=$wpdb->update( 'dc_additional', array( 'addi_value' => $_POST['totaltrsut'] ), array( 'addi_value' => 1 ), array( '%s', '%d' ), array( '%d' ) );
 $successb=$wpdb->update( 'dc_additional', array( 'addi_value' => $_POST['totalreviews'] ), array( 'addi_value' => 2 ), array( '%s', '%d' ), array( '%d' ) );
if($successa && $successb){echo 'data has been save';}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a try